# Is it safe to implement a static method in your executable, which is already implemented in a shared library?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking

We make use of a lot of shared libraries in our code. In this particular case a static method is implemented in one of these libraries. We call this method in different places in our code. However, if we want to test, we would like to isolate the process, so mock the implementation of that method.

The way we are thinking to do this, is by re-implementing the method in the test binary. This would then make sure our implementation is taken instead of the one in the lib.

The main question here is: Is this pure evil? If so, what is the preferred solution for such a case?

An example...

Header of the shared library:

```
static const bool theMethod(...);
```

Implementation of the method in the shared library:

```
static const bool theMethod(...){
  //The real implemetation does some fancy stuff here
  return theRealValue;
}
```

Our test case:

```
#include <headerOfTheMethod.hpp>

//Our own "mocked" implementation
static const bool theMethod(...){
  return true; //Lets say we always return true for the purpose of our test
}

//Here comes our code testing the class which is using that particular method
```

Side note: We are using gcc as compiler, libraries are dynamically linked.

UPDATE: 
*If this would for static methods. That would be a good starter, but what would happen if it were a member function of a class?*

Comment: static member functions of classes *are* member functions of classes. There's no such thing as a "method" in C++, and if you use "method" expecting people to understand that you mean a static member function, well, you'll fool me for one ;-) Same goes if you say "member function" expecting people to understand "non-static member function".

Comment: You should make it a bit more explicit in the code that you are talking about *static **member** functions*.

Answer (score 2):

You would be violating the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_definition_rule). The way that linkers work it's possible that it might work for you, but it's a gamble and there are no guarantees.

Comment: But overriding methods, for instance `malloc` and `free`, using an LD_PRELOAD is common practise and seems to violate this rule, and reliably works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's safe, as long as:

1. Your method works the same as the one you're overriding, externally
2. You avoid linker errors. Check your compiler documentation, but there should be a way to make a symbol as 'weak', so it won't complain about multiple definitions. This is a standard way of overriding functions in system libraries to hook into calls, for testing purposes.